# .subscribe() call is not executed a second time when pressing the browser's back button

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project, I have a route `/blog` which loads the `PostsListComponent`:

```
export class PostsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  posts: Post[];

  categoriesSub: Subscription;
  postsSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
    private postsService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoriesSub = this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(
      categories => {
        // This line is reached now
        this.postsSub = this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
          posts => {
            // This line is not reached
            posts.forEach(p => p.category = categories.find(c => c.id === p.categoryId));
            this.posts = posts;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.categoriesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.postsSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<app-post-item *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post"></app-post-item>
```

Categories service:

```
export class CategoriesService {
  categoriesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category>;
  categories: Observable<Category[]>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.categoriesCollection = this.firestore.collection('categories');

    this.categories = this.categoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Category;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
  }

  getCategory(id: string): Observable<Category> {
    return this.categories.pipe(
      map(categories => categories.find(c => c.id === id))
    );
  }
}
```

And the Posts service:

```
export class PostsService {
  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.firestore.collection('posts');

    this.posts = this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.posts;
  }
}
```

And then I have another route `/blog/:postId` which loads the `FullPostComponent`:

```
export class FullPostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private postsService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const postId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
      posts => {
        this.post = posts.find(p => p.id === postId);
        if (!this.post) {
          window.location.replace('/blog');
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

If I click on a post title when the posts list is displayed it opens the full post for that particular post. But when I hit the browser's back button to go back to the posts list it goes back to the `/blog` route, the `ngOnInit()` on the `PostsListComponent` is called but the `.subscribe()` call is skipped, the posts list remains empty and, as a result, the component displays nothing.

I put a comment in the `PostsListComponent` next to what is skipped.

I don't think it's a router thing since the `ngOnInit()` is called. I'm not that good with services and Observables so I need some help troubleshooting this.

I use Angular 8.

**Edit**: I updated the `PostsListComponents` and added two `.unsubscribe()` calls in the `ngOnDestroy()` method. When reloading the component, the first `.subscribe()` call is executed, the second one is not.

Comment: You need to either call `ngOnDestroy` or read more on the lifecycle events. You're component won't get re-rendered every time.

Comment: I use ```.unsubscribe()``` now but the problem is only half solved. I made an edit.

Comment: You may be getting an error during your service call. Add an error parameter in your subscription call to catch the error.

`this.postsSub = this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
          posts => { ... }, error => { /*put a debugger here to catch the error, if any*/ }`