# Is there a better way to chain .subscribe() calls?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code:

```
this.categoriesSub = this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(
      categories => {
        // This line is reached on the second run
        this.postsSub = this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
          posts => {
            // This line is NOT reached on the second run
            posts.forEach(p => p.category = categories.find(c => c.id === p.categoryId));
            this.posts = posts;
          }
        );
      }
    );
```

Here I'm getting a bunch of posts and for each post, I'm also populating it's `category` field.

It works fine the first time the component is loaded but if I navigate to another route and then hit the back button in the browser to return to this component it doesn't fetch the posts anymore.

Is there a better way to chain `.subscribe()` calls? I've seen examples using `switchMap` but I don't know how I would implement that here. I've tried using a `forkJoin` like this:

```
forkJoin(
      this.categoriesService.getCategories(),
      this.postsService.getPosts()
    ).subscribe(([categories, posts]) => console.log(categories));
```

... just to see if I get the data, but it doesn't work.

**Edit**: To be more precise: The problem is that on the second run, the callback of the second `.subscribe()` call is not executed. There are no errors, no nothing. It looks like it's just skipped. I've added a comment on the line that is not executed.

**Later Edit**: Here is the posts service:

```
export class PostsService {
  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.firestore.collection('posts');

    this.posts = this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.posts;
  }

  getPost(id: string): Observable<Post> {
    return this.posts.pipe(
      map(posts => posts.find(p => p.id === id))
    );
  }
}
```

And here I use `this.posts` in the template:

```
<app-post-item *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post"></app-post-item>
```

And the post item:

```
<div class="post-item" @fade>
    <span class="badge post-category">{{ post.category.name }}</span>
    <a [routerLink]="['./', post.id]" class="post-title text-strong">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <span class="post-date text-medium">{{ post.date.seconds * 1000 | date }}</span><br>
    <img *ngIf="post.coverUrl" class="post-cover-img" src="{{ post.coverUrl }}" alt="none">
    <p class="post-body">{{ postBody }}</p>

    <div class="actions">
        <a [routerLink]="['./', post.id]" class="read-more-button strong">Read More!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both should work. If they don't, then you need to figure out why rather than trying alternate solutions until one happens to work. Read the console for errrors. look at the network panel of your developer tools. Add error callbacks to your subscribe, use your debugger. *it doesn't work* is not very helpful. Tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Also note that forkJoin will not do the same as nested subscriptions. You'll have to read up on rxjs operators and learn to understand how they work and differ from another.

Comment: I added an edit which describes the problem a bit more. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434910/subscribe-call-is-not-executed-a-second-time-when-pressing-the-browsers-back?noredirect=1#comment101347676_57434910) is the problem in more detail.

Comment: OK, so you need to do some analysis then. Why would a callback passed to subscribe never be executed. There aren't that many possibilities. 1. The observable errors instead of emitting. You would know that if you added an eror callback. 2. The observable completes immediately without emitting any event. You would know that if you added a completion callback. 3. the observable doesn't error nor completes. If you added the two previous callbacks, you would know too: none of them would execute. In all cases, you need to read the error if any, and look at the code which creates the observable.

Comment: Yep... No error and no complete.

Comment: You should add a `shareReplay()` pipe after the map operator, to make sure every time you subscribe you get the last snapshot that was emitted before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) emits only when all observables are completed. Try to use [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) instead. But you need to be sure that both observables emit a value or a error. If `getCategories` and `getPosts` are network requests, `zip` is better than `switchMap`, because the requests will be executed in parallel.

```js
zip(
  this.categoriesService.getCategories(),
  this.postsService.getPosts()
).subscribe(([categories, posts]) => {
    posts.forEach(p => p.category = categories.find(c => c.id === p.categoryId));
});
```

---

The root of the problem is that your services share AngularFire observables, which [are hot by design](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1405#issuecomment-356389303). The `getPosts()` and `getCategories()` methods should create new observables instead, like:

```js
export class PostsService {
  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.firestore.collection('posts');
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use subscribe/unsubscribe Observable methods directly. It's very easy to forget to unsubscribe. Use [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe instead, which unsubscribes automatically, when the component is destroyed.

```
@Component({
  template: `<app-post-item *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async [post]="post"></app-post-item>`,
})
class MyComponent {
  readonly posts$: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(
    postsService: PostsService,
    categoriesService: CategoriesService
  ) {
    this.posts$ = zip(
      categoriesService.getCategories(),
      postsService.getPosts()
    ).pipe(
      map(([categories, posts]) => {
      posts.forEach(p => p.category = categories.find(c => c.id === p.categoryId));
      return posts;
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: If the event callback is never executed, using zip() won't help.

Comment: Yes. Same behavior. It works for the first time. But it doesn't anymore on the second run.

Comment: I have something to add here. Using the ```.getPosts()``` directly in the template causes an endless loop. I had to get the observable in the component and then use it in the template.

Comment: @Emil-SorinMalai Yes, my mistake, otherwise new observable will be created on every template update. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was subscribing again to the `postsService` in another component but without calling `.unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` method.

That's why only that call would not work.

Comment: I created a class called "SubscriptionManager" some time ago and I'm using it in all my applications. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/0c4dc13541b863f6503026333eb6b2b6

With it you can easily manage your subscriptions and you only need to call subscrManager.destroy() to destroy all subscriptions in the ngDestroy() function

Comment: But, `getCategories` and `getPosts` methods should work the same, neither you unsubscribe another subscriber or not. Could you add the methods implementation code to the question? Usually you shouldn't use `unsubscribe` method at all inside components, could you describe, how do you use the `this.posts` property?

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov I added the posts service implementation and the templates. The categories service has the same implementation.